# Adding Commas and Decimals

Tags: javascript

The code is functioning without an error. However, I wanted to add commas into the results. When I console.log the equation I get the correct output. However, my function thousands_seperators does not show correctly on the web page.

My code is below:

```
if (isFinite(monthly)) {
    // monthlyPayment.value = monthly.toFixed(2)
    // totalPayment.value = (monthly * calculatedPayments).toFixed(2);
    // totalInterest.value = ((monthly * calculatedPayments) - principal).toFixed(2);

    // UPDATE TO ADD DECIMAL POINTS
    function thousands_separators(num) {
        var num_parts = num.toString().split(".");
        num_parts[0] = num_parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
        return num_parts.join(".");
    }

    console.log(thousands_separators(monthlyPayment.value = monthly.toFixed(2)));
    console.log(thousands_separators(totalPayment.value = (monthly * calculatedPayments).toFixed(2)));
    console.log(thousands_separators(totalInterest.value = ((monthly * calculatedPayments) - principal).toFixed(2)));

    // SHOW RESULTS
    document.getElementById("results").style.display = "block";
    // HIDE LOADER
    document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";

} else {
    showError("Please check that all fields are filled out")
}
```

Comment: Please specify what issue you are having in the question. Your function seems to be working properly.

Comment: I don't see a question, and it isn't clear what the issue is.

Comment: The code is functioning without an error. However, I wanted to add commas into the results. When I console.log the equation I get the correct output. However, my function thousands_seperators does not show correctly on the web page.

Comment: where are you outputting it? nevermind..... lost it in the console.log mess.

Answer (score 0):

Let us break down this code:

This is how it works

```
var result = ((monthly * calculatedPayments) - principal).toFixed(2)
totalInterest.value = result
console.log(thousands_separators(result));
```

See the problem? You put the thousands_separators at wrong place.

Doing something in one line is not really great for readability and hence why you got this problem. Use variables, do things in multiple steps.

```
var result = ((monthly * calculatedPayments) - principal).toFixed(2)
var formatted = thousands_separators(result)
totalInterest.value = formatted
console.log(formatted);
```